# Cloudera manager while installation , get HostName

Tags: python-2.7, ip-address, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

As a student we were asked to implement a cloudier cluster using Vm’s , i tried to install cloudier cluster using 3 Vm’s under ubuntu 14.01 ,
My steps so far : 
I used ssh passwordless connection between all nodes , (tested )
Configure /etc/hosts to all my vm’s
installed cloudera CDH ,
the problem occurs when i try to install every thing on each node this thing occurs .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WPvf.png)

but whats make me so unconfident about this its it identify perfectly my hosts names and address in the pre-installation 
[enter image description here][2]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzhYL.png)
but when i try to install it fails and give me  the error mentioned ,
so i tried to see if python dont recognize my hostnames so i went on some codes to test and every thing worked perfectly :

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyname("master1")
'10.211.55.13'
>>> socket.gethostbyname("slave1")
'10.211.55.11'
>>> socket.gethostbyname("slave2")
'10.211.55.12'
>>>
```

my /etc/hosts file its similar to all hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
#127.0.1.1  ubuntu
10.211.55.13 master1.bdsas.com master1
10.211.55.11 slave1.bdsas.com slave1
10.211.55.12 slave2.bdsas.com slave2

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: can u reach all adresses using ping?

Answer (score 0):

CDH does not support IPv6 (see this link: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cdh_ig_req_supported_versions.html) and search for IPv6. Turn off IPv6 in your network configuration and see if that resolves the issue.